# Can I post-redden blood oranges?

Tags: temperature, oranges, ripe, peel

Blood oranges turn red by experiencing night frost. Many places say that citrus don't post-ripen after picking. Does that extend to the color change, or could I subject non-red blood oranges to a temperature cycle and see them turn red before they turn bad? Would it take mediterranean heat in daytime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe....there are several scientific papers on blood oranges.  [Here is one example](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0308814620321968) that speaks to conditioning the fruit:

> This study shows that the qualitative and quantitative composition of the anthocyanin pigments and other flavonoids such as flavanones, flavones and flavonols in blood orange fruit and juice could be enhanced by conditioning the fruit at 37 °C for 3 days (curing) and storage at 9 °C from 30 to 45 days.